# Meditation app for Android with minimal permissions

Tags: android, relaxation

Looking for a meditation app where I can set an arbitrary time to meditate with a pleasant bell sound to end and without excessive permissions.

Ideally no:

- In app purchases
- Photos/Media/Files
- Device ID/call info
- run at a startup

Comment: I didn't investigate Meditation apps (yet), so I've got no list ready for that. While waiting for answers, you could do some research on your own: Get yourself Galen's [StripSearch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hasslefixes.stripsearch) app installed, and use it to search for "Meditation" and a corresponding permission-filter set. This app is exactly for issues like yours: finding an app for specific tasks with minimal permissions. You can setup your own permission definitions, or use one of the pre-defined sets. Good luck – also with answers here!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Meditation Timer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clay.meditation)? Seems to be minimalistic and neat:

- can set time for meditation,
- I found the bell sound to be rather nice,
- no in app purchases (from what I've seen),
- required permissions: change your audio settings and set an alarm,
- not sure whether runs at startup or not though.

Maybe worth a look.